# Replicating Logic: Count Distinct

Tags: sql

I am trying to replicate the following logic:

I am trying a write a query where I have to compare order no and coupon code of certain products. When an order no > 1, I generate multiple unique coupon codes. Now I want to count these order no with unique coupon codes and store them as **Quantities**.

**Example** - there are 3 orders with order number- '1' and each order has a unique Coupon Code = 111,222,333 so quantity should be 1 for each unique coupon code. Similarly for order no '2' there are two coupon codes= 444, 555, hence quantity should be 1 again (coupon code is unique again).

| Order no | Coupon Code | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 111 | 1 |
| 1 | 222 | 1 |
| 1 | 333 | 1 |
| 2 | 444 | 1 |
| 2 | 555 | 1 |

One possible solution is to compare the values in both the columns and then evaluate the quantity no possibly by dividing the count (distinct of order no) with count (distinct of voucher code for that particular order no). I am having a hard time writing one since these are not the only columns I am dealing with, there are 20 other columns, 10 other joins, and group by columns, so writing a derived table etc. is cumbersome and not possible (I think).

Answer (score 0):

For your sample data, you can simply use:

```
select t.*, 1 as quantity
from t;
```

However the more general solution is window functions:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by order_no, coupon_code) as quantity
from t;
```